# Logitech m235 doesn't work

Tags: mouse, logitech

That is the error, I get when I try to work with it.

```
Jul  9 09:09:56 me kernel: [ 2740.896079] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.080112] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52f
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.080118] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.080121] usb 4-2: Product: USB Receiver
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.080124] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.088728] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input15
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.088877] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2/input0
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.093420] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/input/input16
Jul  9 09:09:57 me kernel: [ 2741.094363] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2/input1
Jul  9 09:09:57 me mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2"
Jul  9 09:09:57 me mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 4 was not an MTP device
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: The device seems to be detected properly, the last two lines containing `mtp-probe` have nothing to do with mouse functionality. As far as I know unifying receiver mice should work just fine (when you use each mouse with a dedicated receiver, that is, so no unifying out of the box). What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same mouse with Mint 14 (Ubuntu-based), and it never works from a fresh boot, but unplug and re-plug the USB receiver and it works perfectly.

I normally 'suspend' rather than 'shutdown', and it always works fine when I 'resume', so the problem seems to be in the initial start-up. I've not investigated further, as the workaround is so quick and simple.